# Solution of coupled ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(u,v,f,g)$ are functions of $t$.

How to solve second order Diffrl. Equations

$$ u^{''}=gg',\, v^{''}=ff'/m^2,\, f'/g'=m $$

if primes denote differentiation with respect to $t$ and $m$ is a real constant?

Trial /error/guess gives first derivative of $(u,v)$ as $ (\sin v/m , \sin u) $ types but how do we obtain a general solution? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Where from you got these equations ? Can you provide the actual question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can trivially integrate all equations
$$
2u'=g^2+C,~~2m^2v'=f^2+D,~~f=mg+E.
$$
Now you could eliminate $f$ from the second equation, and that is all that is possible to deduce with the given data. One could of course write the remaining derivative relations as integral relations, $2u=\int(g^2+C)dt$ etc., but that gives not further insight.